# Find first two terms in solution for integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I am asked to find the first two terms in the of the solution to the integral

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{rx}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x$$

as $r\to0$. So firstly,

\begin{align}
I &= r\int_0^\infty \frac{1+x-1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x \\
&=r\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}}\,{\rm d}x-r\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x \\
&=2-r\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x =2-rI_1\\
\end{align}

Now let $\delta\gg r^2$ and $\delta\ll 1$ so that

$$I_1 = \int_0^\delta\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x+\int_\delta^\infty \frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x$$

Note that in the first integral $x\le\delta\ll1$ so we may expand $(1+x)^{-1}$ and in the second, $x\ge\delta\gg r^2$ so we may expand $(r^2+x)^{-3/2}=x^{-3/2}(1+r^2x^{-1})^{-3/2}$. This gives

\begin{align}
I_1 &= \int_0^\delta\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}}(1-x+\ldots)\,{\rm d}x+\int_\delta^\infty \frac{1}{x^{3/2}(1+x)}\left(1-\frac{3r^2}{2x}+\ldots\right)\,{\rm d}x \\
&= \int_0^\delta\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}}\,{\rm d}x-\int_0^\delta\frac{x}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}}\,{\rm d}x+\int_\delta^\infty \frac{1}{x^{3/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x-\frac{3r^2}2\int_\delta^\infty \frac{1}{x^{5/2}(1+x)}\,{\rm d}x\\
&= J_1-J_2+J_3-\frac{3r^2}2J_4
\end{align}

All of which are integrable and (skipping the working) integrate to

$$J_1=\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x+r^2}}\right]_0^\delta=\frac2r-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\delta+r^2}}$$

$$J_2=\left[\frac{2(x+2r^2)}{\sqrt{x+r^2}}\right]_0^\delta=\frac{2(\delta+2r^2)}{\sqrt{\delta+r^2}}-4r$$

$$J_3=\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}-2\arctan{(\sqrt{x})}\right]_\delta^\infty = -\pi+\frac2{\sqrt{\delta}}+2\arctan{(\sqrt{\delta})}$$

$$J_4=\left[\frac{6x-2}{x^{3/2}}+2\arctan{(\sqrt{x})}\right]_\delta^\infty = \pi-\frac{6\delta-2}{\delta^{3/2}}-2\arctan{(\sqrt{\delta})}$$

So we have that

\begin{align}
I_1&=\frac2r-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\delta+r^2}}-\frac{2(\delta+2r^2)}{\sqrt{\delta+r^2}}+4r-\pi+\frac2{\sqrt{\delta}}+2\arctan{(\sqrt{\delta})}-\frac{3r^2\pi}2-\frac{3r^2(3\delta-1)}{\delta^{3/2}}-3r^2\arctan{(\sqrt{\delta})}\\
&=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\delta^2+r}}(2r^2+\delta+1)+\frac2r(2r^2+1)-\frac\pi2(3r^2+2)+(2-3r^2)\arctan{(\sqrt{\delta})}+\delta^{-3/2}(2\delta-3r^2(3\delta-1))
\end{align}

and finally,

$$I=2+\frac{2r}{\sqrt{\delta^2+r}}(2r^2+\delta+1)-2(2r^2+1)+\frac\pi2r(3r^2+2)-r(2-3r^2)\arctan{(\sqrt{\delta})}-r\delta^{-3/2}(2\delta-3r^2(3\delta-1))$$

However, now I'm stuck because we don't want $\delta$'s in the final solution (since they weren't included in the question). How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I do not know if this is an answer since I do not follow your path.*

In all the following, I shall assume $r>0$.

Considering the integrand in $I_1$ $$\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}=\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{1/2}}\left(\frac{1}{(r^2+x)(1+x)} \right)$$ Now using partial fraction decomposition $$\frac{1}{(r^2+x)(1+x)}=\frac  1{1-r^2}\left(\frac{1}{ r^2+x}-\frac{1}{
   x+1}\right)$$ $$\frac{1}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}=\frac  1{1-r^2}\left(\frac{1}{ (r^2+x)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{
   (x+1)(r^2+x)^{1/2}}\right)$$ $$(1-r^2)I_1=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{ (r^2+x)^{3/2}}-\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{
   (x+1)(r^2+x)^{1/2}}=\frac 2r-\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{
   (x+1)(r^2+x)^{1/2}}$$ Now, the unpleasant part (I shall let it to you) $$J=\int \frac{dx}{
   (x+1)(r^2+x)^{1/2}}=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r^2+x}{r^2+1}}\right)$$ which makes $$K=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{
   (x+1)(r^2+x)^{1/2}}=\frac{\pi -2 \sin ^{-1}(r)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$ All of this makes $$(1-r^2)I_1=\frac 2r-\frac{\pi -2 \sin ^{-1}(r)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$ $$I=2-\frac r{{1-r^2}}\left(\frac 2r-\frac{\pi -2 \sin ^{-1}(r)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)$$ Now, use Taylor series around $r=0$.

Being sure that you will properly finish, let me show how good is the approximation using the first two terms 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \text{r} & \text{exact} & \text{approx} \\
 0.1 & 0.278391 & 0.274159 \\
 0.01 & 0.0310206 & 0.0310159 \\
 0.001 & 0.00313760 & 0.00313759 \\
 0.0001 & 0.000314119 & 0.000314119 \\
 0.00001 & 0.0000314155 & 0.0000314155
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

I did not have enough time on yesterday to add a few comments :

- as long as $r$ is finite, the is no problem since Taylor expansions of the integrand are $$f=\frac{rx}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}$$  $$f=\frac{x}{r^2}-\frac{\left(2 r^2+3\right) x^2}{2 r^4}+O\left(x^3\right)\qquad \qquad (x\to0)$$ $$f=\frac{r}{x^{3/2}}-r\left(\frac{3 r^2}{2}+1\right) \frac{1}{x^{5/2}}
     +O\left(\frac{1}{x^{7/2}}\right)\qquad \qquad (x\to \infty)$$ So, for a given non-zero value of $r$, there was no need to decompose the integration interval using $\delta$.
- May be, you will be interested by the fact that the antiderivative of $f$ is simply $$\int \frac{rx}{(r^2+x)^{3/2}(1+x)}\,dx=\frac{r }{1-r^2}\left(\frac{2 r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+x}}+\frac{2 \tan
     ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2+x}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)$$